# Invalid Type Error while using Msgpack with Flask and AngularJS

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, msgpack

I have a simple Flask app like so:

```
import msgpack
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return msgpack.packb([1, 2, 3])

@app.route('/ping')
def ping():
    return "Pong"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

In the Flask route `/test`, I'm using msgpack to pack an array which is returned as a response. When this response is printed to the console, it looks something like this: `b'\x93\x01\x02\x03'`

I'm using AngularJS 1.7 in my front end which looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <body ng-cloak>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MyController">
      <h1>Hello, {{text}}</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ping()">Ping</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getMsgpackData()">Get Msgpack Data</button>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/kawanet/msgpack-lite/master/dist/msgpack.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);

      myApp.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.text = "World";

        $scope.ping = function() {
          $http.get("/ping").then(function success(response) {
              $scope.text = response.data;
          }, function error(response) {
              console.log(response);
          });
        }

        $scope.getMsgpackData = function() {
          $http.get("/test").then(function success(response) {
              console.log(response);
              $scope.text = msgpack.decode(response.data);
          }, function error(response) {
              console.log(response);
          });
        }
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the `getMsgpackData` function is invoked in `MyController`, I get the following error in the browser's console:

```
Error: Invalid type: 0x�
    at n.r [as decode] (msgpack.min.js:1)
    at n.fetch (msgpack.min.js:1)
    at n.s [as read] (msgpack.min.js:1)
    at Object.n [as decode] (msgpack.min.js:1)
    at success ((index):46)
    at angular.js:17396
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18557)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18945)
    at k (angular.js:12799)
    at V (angular.js:13056) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
```

It seems like the first HEX value `\x93` is not being decoded.

I'm using [kawanet/msgpack-lite](https://github.com/kawanet/msgpack-lite) in the front end as I found that it can be used in a browser.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you you sent the wrong type of object to the `decode()` method. The [buffer decoding documentation](https://github.com/kawanet/msgpack-lite#decoding-messagepack-bytes-array) shows that only buffers, arrays and `Uint8Array` objects are supported.

Change the response type to `arraybuffer` (from the default `text`), then feed the response data to `msgpack.decode()` as a `Uint8Array` typed array:

```js
$http.get("/test", {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).then(function success(response) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(response.data);
    console.log(arr);
    $scope.text = msgpack.decode(arr);
}, function error(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

While not necessary here, you do want to set a different content type on your Flask response. Currently the `/test` route is advertising the content as `text/html`, while you really should be labelling as `application/msgpack`:

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return msgpack.packb([1, 2, 3]), {'content-type': 'application/msgpack'}
```